# can I submmit same looking app to apple iTunes and google play stores

Tags: android, ios, iphone

I'm building a platform in which real estates agents can register and get their own app that I'll upload for them to the apple iTunes and google play stores.

the app will be under their name (different name for each app base on the name of the real estate agent)

the account that I'm going to upload all the apps from is my account that I have for apple and google store.

so can I upload the same app many times,the content of the app is different base on the properties of the real estate agent,but the ui is pretty much the same.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the terms of service for distribution channels, not programming.

Answer (score 0):

If the content is different then there shouldn't be problem. The issue I would have is as an estate agent, at the bottom of my apps page, there will be links to my competitors under the section "Other apps by this developer".

Comment: No problem. If is answers your question you should mark it as so. Thanks.